# How to configure Apache2 to pretend a directory does not exist, except under a specific URI?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, config

How do I make Apache2 treat a directory as if it doesn't exist, in order to prevent someone from finding out that it exists?

The directory will still be accessible under a different URI. For example, in the following `.htaccess` file, I would like any attempt to access `example.com/admin` (or a subdirectory or file inside of `/admin/`) to continue down to the `index.php` rewrite rule, unless it was accessed via `/MySecretPath`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^MySecretPath$ admin/ [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^MySecretPath/(.*)$ admin/$1 [L,QSA]
# all remaining requests - sent to the script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: rename `admin/` folder to `MySecretPath/`?

Comment: @dusan.bajic Renaming the directory requires changing the paths auto-configured inside the PHP script. The htaccess solution is easy to do and maintain for a large number of directories.

Comment: yes, I figured there must be a reason, but I was just being a smartass since you did not explicitly mention that :)

Comment: @dusan.bajic That's fair :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable external access to the dir, put this rule above your existing rules :

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /admin/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

You can change the **F** "forbidden" to **R=404** if you want the engine to return a 404 not found error for the request

Comment: Hm, that looks good, but in this case the 404 handler is index.php. I think your code will work if I change the RewriteRule to send to index.php - I'll give it a shot when I get a chance.